# jquery show/hide content in div without hardcoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs, there is content(images) inside of them. When you click on one of them content of it becomes visible and content of other two becomes hidden. I've been managed to achieve that with jquery code(you can check for it below), but the bad thing it's hardcoded, is there any other methods do do it?

P.S.: "https://solomia-gera.github.io/" is the site itself if you want to have a look.

---------------------------------------------------------THE CODE-----------------------------------------------------

```
<!-- Hide/Show DIV1 content-->
<script>
// Hide content in div with id#mox when cliked on div with id#content
  $("#mox2").on("click", function () {
  $("#content1").hide();
  });
  $("#mox3").on("click", function () {
  $("#content1").hide();
  });
// Show content in div with id#mox when cliked on div with id#content
  $("#mox1").on("click", function () {
  $("#content1").show();
  });
</script>

<!-- Hide/Show DIV2 content-->
<script>
  $("#content2").hide();
// Hide content in div with id#mox when cliked on div with id#content
  $("#mox1").on("click", function () {
  $("#content2").hide();
  });
  $("#mox3").on("click", function () {
  $("#content2").hide();
  });
// Show content in div with id#mox when cliked on div with id#content
  $("#mox2").on("click", function () {
  $("#content2").show();
  });
</script>

<!-- Hide/Show DIV3 content-->
<script>
$("#content3").hide();
// Hide content in div with id#mox when cliked on div with id#content
 $("#mox2").on("click", function () {
 $("#content3").hide();
  });
 $("#mox1").on("click", function () {
 $("#content3").hide();
 });
  // Show content in div with id#mox when cliked on div with id#content
 $("#mox3").on("click", function () {
 $("#content3").show();
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that all three have a common class `mox`, and if you add a common class `content` to each of the content divs you can do this:

```
$(".mox").click(function() {
    $(this).children(".content").show();
    $(".mox").not(this).children(".content").hide();
}
```

Explanation: the function is called whenever you click on any element with a `mox` class. `this` selector lets you select the particular instance of the class that was clicked, `children()` selects any child elements and when we put a selector as an argument for `children()`, it selects all child elements that match that selector. Second line works similarly, with an addition of `not(this)`, so the second line reads hide all elements that match `content` class and are children of any element with class `mox`, but this one.

EDIT: If for some reason you do not want to assign a common class to all content divs, the following function will work as is:

```
$(".mox").click(function() {
    $(this).children("[id^=content]").show();
    $(".mox").not(this).children("[id^=content]").hide();
}
```

Here I used `attributeStartsWith` selector, [read more here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: this answer is great, I've implemented your method in my code, everything is working but 1 thing is annoying. For some reason on page load i see the contents of div2 and div3 for 1/10th of second or so and the screen shakes really bad. I've only noticed this on Chrome, Firefox is doing well. What might it be?
P.S.: I've updated the web-site with the code so you can have a look at that bug.

Comment: @r.hrytskiv You hide div2 and div3 only on page load, which could lead to problems like that. Since the script on your page always hides div2 and div3 on page load no matter what, you should remove that part of the script (`$("#content2").hide();$("#content3").hide();`) and instead add `style="display:none;"` to both div2 and div3 so they're never shown on load.

Answer (score 1):

There is much better way for doing this
You can simply use the following code

```
$('.content').on('click', '.img-heading', function(){
    $(this).parent('.content').siblings('.content').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('.content').addClass('active');
})
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/WpZeYX)

Comment: Found this really helpful. Thanks @Abinthaha

Answer (score 0):

if your content is outside `mox`, you can apply a same class for each element and add a data for show only what you want.

```js
$(".mox").on("click", function () {
  var content = $(".content")
  content.hide();
  content.eq($(this).attr("data-content")-1).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mox" data-content="1">Show one</div>
<div class="mox" data-content="2">Show two</div>
<div class="mox" data-content="3">Show three</div>

<div class="content" style="display:none;width:100px;height:100px; background:red" ></div>
<div class="content" style="display:none;width:100px;height:100px; background:blue" ></div>
<div class="content" style="display:none;width:100px;height:100px; background:green" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
    $('.mox').on('click', function(){
      $('.image_list').hide();
      var $index  = $('.mox').index(this);
      $('.image_list').eq($index).show();
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="box">
      <div id="mox1" class="mox">
        <p class="hide">
        O<br>V<br>E<br>R<br>V<br>I<br>E<br>W
        </p>
          <div id="content1" class="image_list">
      <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/1.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/2.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/3.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/4.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/5.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/6.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/7.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/8.jpg">
          </div>
      </div>

    <!-- ALBUMS -->
      <div id="mox2" class="mox">
        <p class="">
        A<br>L<br>B<br>U<br>M<br>S
        </p>
          <div id="content2" class="image_list">
     <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/1.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/2.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/3.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/4.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/5.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/6.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/7.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/8.jpg">
          </div>
      </div>

    <!-- ABOUT -->
      <div id="mox3" class="mox">
        <p class="">
        A<br>B<br>O<br>U<br>T
        </p>
          <div id="content3" class="image_list">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/1.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/2.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/3.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/4.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/5.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/6.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/7.jpg">
            <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/8.jpg">
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:

```js
function myCustomHide(contentIds, moxsIds){
 contentIds.forEach(function(element, index) { 
  index !== 0 ? $("#"+element).hide(): null;
  moxsIds.forEach(function(moxElem, moxIndex){
      if(index !== moxIndex){
        $("#"+moxElem).on("click", function(){
             $("#"+element).hide();
        });
      }
   });
    $("#"+moxsIds[index]).on("click", function(){
          $("#"+element).show();
    });
 });
}

var contentsIds = [ "content1", "content2", "content3"];
var moxsIds = [ "mox1", "mox2", "mox3"];

myCustomHide(contentsIds, moxsIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
      <div id="mox1">
          Overview
      </div>
      <div id="content1" class="image_list">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/1.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/2.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/3.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/4.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/5.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/6.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/7.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/8.jpg">
      </div>

    <!-- ALBUMS -->
      <div id="mox2">
        Albums
        </div>
      <div id="content2" class="image_list">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/1.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/2.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/3.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/4.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/5.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/6.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/7.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/8.jpg">
      </div>
      

    <!-- ABOUT -->
      <div id="mox3">
        About
        </div>
      <div id="content3" class="image_list">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/1.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/2.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/3.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/4.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/5.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/6.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/7.jpg">
        <img src="https://solomia-gera.github.io/img/8.jpg">
      </div>
      

    </div>
```

or check the fiddle for slight different html: https://jsfiddle.net/oy7vj7fq/2/